# Understanding Memory Addressing in Python

Tags: python, pointers, memory-address

I am writing this to expand my understanding of how `pointers` and `memory-addressing` work in `python`.

Python being a high level language, I have learned that the memory management is taken care of by python.

I have also learned that the pointers can be identified with `id()` object.

Assume I have two variables `a` and `b`, and these two variables can be swapped with the below command:

```
a,b=b,a
```

The change in `identity` of these variables can be found using the below methods.

```
>>> a=2
>>> b=3
>>> id(a)
140732857872688
>>> id(b)
140732857872720
>>> a,b=b,a
>>> a
3
>>> b
2
>>> id(a)
140732857872720
>>> id(b)
140732857872688
```

As you can see the `ids` are swapped (as expected) , and in the other words we can say the `ids`assigned to variable are swapped. How is this happening in python?

And in one more example,

```
>>> i=0
>>> id(i)
140732857872624
>>> i+=1
>>> id(i)
140732857872656
```

When `i` is incremented by `1` , how is a new variable( I am calling it new because the identity is changing) with the same name created under the hood?

I am adding one more example also to further expand my question!

Operation 1:

```
>>> i,j=0,0
>>> id(i)
140732857872624
>>> id(j)
140732857872624
>>> i,j = i+1,i+1
>>> i
1
>>> j
1
>>> id(i)
140732857872656
>>> id(j)
140732857872656
```

Operation 2:

```
>>> i,j=0,0
>>> i=i+1
>>> j=i+1
>>> i
1
>>> j
2
>>> id(i)
140732857872656
>>> id(j)
140732857872688
```

Of course operation 1 and operation 2 are different. How do both of these operations occur at a low level.

And once there is no more use for an already assigned pointer, how will it get reused ? if a `memory-address` can not be reused in a given program and new `memory-address` has to be given for each new operation(in the same program) , is it the reason behind memory overflow when `recursion` with a high depth is used?

I hope I have made my questions clear.

If my understanding is wrong anywhere , please correct me. Coming from Mechanical Engineering background, although I have been programming for quite some time , this thing is really confusing to me.

Regards

Comment: Python *doesn't have pointers*

Comment: Variables don't have IDs. An ID is a property of an *object*, not a variable.

Comment: ids are not assigned to variables in python. Variables reference objects and those objects have ids. You swapped `a` and `b`, and the objects referenced by `a` and `b` retained their id. The memory location used for the map of `a` to the object can jump around all over the place. Nothing says that part is static.

Comment: Just like how you don't usually think about transistors in C, it's usually best to think about objects instead of memory in Python.

Comment: This is a good thing to read if you want to get a handle on how variables and assignments work in python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `dis` to see what's happening under the hood.

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: def swap(): a=1; b=2; a,b=b,a

In [3]: dis.dis(swap)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 ROT_TWO
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's in [this talk](https://youtu.be/sPiWg5jSoZI).

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is happening a simple mental model is

1. **Every python variable is a pointer.**
   Even after `i=1` internally in Python `i` is a pointer to an object that contains the value 1. Even integers are normal objects (this is not very common as in other languages normally variables end up containing the values directly for small integers).
2. **For efficiency reasons some immutable objects are cached and shared.** 
   Small integers are cached so in a Python program if you all the variables with value `0` will be pointers pointing to the same object.
   In the second case you are observing different `id`s because the value is different (`i` will be pointing to 1 and `j` will be pointing to 2).
   Note that sharing is done only for **immutable** objects because, except by using `id` the sharing cannot be observed in the code. In Python this is done for small numbers and some small strings (those that end up being "interned").

Answer (score 1):

in python, variables are memory references. when you create

```
a=2
```

python memory manager will place this value `2` inside a slot of memory heap, and assign the address of this memory slot to the variable. Essentially

```
a=adress_of_this_memory_slot
```

Behind the scene whenever you call **a**, python memory manager looks at the address and retrieves the value.

Python memory manager automatically reuses the memory references if the objects are **immutable**. In your case integers are immutable objects. So python reusing objects on demand and this is called **INTERNING** in python.

At start-up python preloads or caches the a global list of integers in the range [-5,256]. Anytime an integer is referenced in this range Python will use the cached version of that object.

So based on your first example, you created:

```
a=2
b=3
```

So python memory manager will add those values into two different slots of memory heap. in your example their address are:

```
id(a) ==> 140732857872688 
id(b) ==> 140732857872720
```

After this point any time you want to use `int 2,3` python will use this memory addresses for the optimization purpose.

try your examples with integers out of this range [-5,256]. you will see that python will recreate a new address for this variable, in other words python will not share references for these values.